# Maven parent version ${revision} expansion in cross project inheritance

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-versions-plugin, flatten-maven-plugin

**Background:**
I'm using maven 3.5 and have a 'master' aggregator project which has 4 modules (uses both aggregation and inheritance).
I also have 30 separate child projects, both single and multi-module, which each inherit from one of those 4 modules.

**Problem:**

I'd like to use `${revision}` in the `<parent><version>` tag of the child projects but what I observe is maven trying to resolve the parent before expanding `${revision}` (to the value specified in `<properties><revision>`). This results in maven being unable to resolve the parent since it's looking for the literal "${revision}" version of the parent project.

**Questions**

- Is it true that `${revision}` does not work for cross project inheritance ?
- is there any work around ? (while trying to avoid maven-versions plugin)

*Note: I'm able to use `${revision}` without any problems in a single multi-module project - that's not the issue.*

Comment: So each of the 30 child projects has one of the 4 modules as parent?

Comment: yes that's correct - they're linked by inheritance

Comment: So I assume that these four modules are POM projects. Did you define the property `revision` in the topmost POM?

Comment: yep pom projects, revision in topmost. Revision property is also set in the child project, so it knows how to find the parent project (i.e in nexus/artifactoy)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, but it works for me with maven 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue and had to use a flatten plugin in my parent pom.  First, you add the revision in the properties

```
<properties>
    <revision>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <mssql-jdbc.version>9.4.1.jre11</mssql-jdbc.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <flatten-maven-plugin.version>1.1.0</flatten-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Then add this plugin to the build section

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flatten-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```